# Relative path for prisma generator provider

Tags: bash, prisma

I have a custom prisma generator inside my nodejs project.
The problem is, that the `provider` field for the generator is relative. I can't publish it as package.
I will call the the generator from different places based on context (ci pipeline, testing, development, etc)

Example:

```
generator nexus {
  provider = "node ../modules/prisma-generator-custom"
  output   = "./generated"
}
```

Since Prisma supports bash to some degree, I tried using `$BASH_SOURCE[0]` for accessing a full path, but it is always relative to the path I am calling from, not the directory of the file.

Thank you for any ideas.